# Errors from Sklearn, python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am learning python/ML and have come across these errors.  I have no clue since the code is good.

**Code**

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = mglearn.datasets.make_forge()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 4))
line = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000).reshape(-1, 1)
for n_neighbors, ax in zip ([1,3,9], axes):
    reg = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=n_neighbors)
    reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    ax.plot(line, reg.predict(line))
    ax.plot(X_train, y_train, '^', c=mglearn.cm2(0), markersize=8)
    ax.plot(X_test, y_test, 'v', c=mglearn.cm2(1), markersize=8)

    ax1.set_title(
        "{} neighour(s)\n train score: {:.2f} test score: {:.2f}".format(
            n_neighbors, reg.score(X_train, y_train),
            reg.score(X_test, y_test)))
    ax.set_xlabel("feature")
    ax.set_ylabel("target")
axes[0].legend(['model predictions', 'training data/target',
    'test data/target'], loc='best')
```

**Errors**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ch2.py", line 161, in <module>
    ax.plot(line, reg.predict(line))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\regression.py", line 144, in predict
    neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 385, in kneighbors
    for s in gen_even_slices(X.shape[0], n_jobs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 779, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 625, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 588, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 111, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 332, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "sklearn\neighbors\binary_tree.pxi", line 1294, in sklearn.neighbors.kd_tree.BinaryTree.query
ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension
```

I can't seem to figure out what the error is, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is mglearn? I'm getting "NameError: name 'mglearn' is not defined"

Comment: `X_train` is (likely) N by 2 dimensions, while `line` is M by 1 dimensions. You'd want that to be M by 2 dimensions, to match `X_train`, your training data.

Answer (score 1):

As others have remarked, X and line have different numbers of features. This is an example from my book, full code [here](https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python).

```
X, y = mglearn.datasets.make_wave()
```

will give you the 1d dataset that is used in the book and the notebooks I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

You did forget to import Mglearn. It can be installed in Ubuntu via pip install Mglearn . After that, 
Import mglearn 
it will start working, same happened with me!!